# Usage of "estar com"

Tags: gramática, verbos, tradução-inglês

I have seen *estar com [noun]* frequently and think I grasp the meaning:

- When a living creature *esta com* an abstract object (like cold or thirst), they feel it; and
- with other objects, they have temporary possession.

However, I am not clear on when it can or should be used. Here is an example:**

> Eu estou com a sua TV.

I read this as "I have your TV." Could I use *Eu tenho a sua TV* instead? Coming from Spanish, that sounds a lot more natural to me. If I can use it, does it carry a different meaning? More generally, in which cases is one (of *estar com* and *ter*) a good fit, while the other is ungrammatical or sounds unnatural?

*** I took [the example](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/165402) from a Brazilian Portuguese course on Duolingo.*

Comment: I suspect *estar com* is specific to Brazil, but won't tag it unless someone tells me that's the case.

Comment: *Eu tenho a sua TV* sounds wrong in Brazil. *Ter* does transmit a sense of stability, although it can be used to mean something temporary or fixed in time depending on the context.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the example sentence is wrong (in all variants of Portuguese). What are you trying to say?

Comment: @someonewithpc I've added a sentence explaining what I think the example means in English (which is also what Duolingo tells me it means). Are you saying the "estar com" version is wrong or the "ter" version (which I made up based on what "ter" means)?

Comment: The one provided on the website; the one you constructed _is_ correct.

Comment: @someonewithpc I suspect is is a dialect thing, with the "estar com" version being preferred in Brazil (even if it is, in some sense, wrong). As you see in the comment above, bfavaretto finds the "ter" version unnatural-sounding.

Comment: @bfavaretto Dizer-se coisas como "eu estou com a sua TV" ou "eu estou com as suas chaves (você as deixou no meu gabinete)" é normal no Brasil? Procurei na net, mas não encontrei muitos exemplos.

Comment: @Jacinto É normal no Brasil sim.

Comment: If you said "Eu tenho a sua TV" I'd think (1) you have the same TV model; or (2) it would sound illogical because if you have it then it's yours, not mine anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Eu estou com a sua TV" means "I've got your TV"― probably I borrowed it from you and didn't give it back to you yet. Or you forgot you left it in my house, and I'm reminding you.

If I say "Eu tenho a sua TV" (I have your TV), it would sound like I stole it or took it away from you and now it's in my possession. In my experience, it would also sound strange, and people use "estou com" more often.

You can also use it when you want to say that there's someone else with you, like in this conversation:

> ―Você está sozinho? (Are you alone?)
>
> ―Não, estou com meu irmão. (No, I'm with my brother)

Comment: I've always thought this question needed a better answer, or at least another point of view. Good you wrote one. But I don't think English speakers will say "I'm with your TV"; "I've got your TV" is better.

Comment: @Jacinto I agree that "I've got your TV" is better. I added it  to the answer, thanks!

Comment: This is a very interesting pattern that I didn't know existed in Portuguese, but with an underlying logic that appears in many languages: "being with X" or "being next to X" is often a periphrasis for possession. The logic is the same that makes *uma rosa com muitos espinhos* equivalent to *uma rosa que tem muitos espinhos*.

Comment: @pablodf76 and vice-versa. _I'm with you in this feud_ has the same meaning of _I stand by you in this feud_ or _I've got you in this feud_.

Comment: Hugo, I don't know if you were going for the shock value, so I didn't edit. But, instead of _kidnapped_, you could go with _stole_ or _taken away_.

Comment: @RamonMelo Actually, it was the first word that came up when I was writing. I'm going to edit the answer, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I know _sequestrar_ is a common idiom for holding things owned by other people here in Brazil, but I wasn't sure if that's what you wanted to mean.

Comment: Hugo, I've just made a few minor changes. I trust you like long dashes. You know where the rollback button is if you don't.

Comment: @Jacinto English speakers won't ever say  "I'm with your T.V." but Brazilians speaking english certainly will.  Brazilians speaking English often say things like "are you with your keys" or "Sorry for not replying, I was without battery."  Hugo great answer but you should probably remove the "I'm with your T.V" example from your answer altogether as native speakers wouldn't say it :)

Comment: @Some_Guy, yes, we poor non-native speakers bring along our own Portuguese structures  when speaking in English. But that one I was pretty sure was not idiomatic English.

Comment: @Jacinto faço a mesma coisa com a tua idioma frequentemente :)

Answer (score 3):

The *estar com* construction is much more common than the transliteration *to be with* in English (although it does also mean that).

In many cases it is better translated idiomatically as *have*.  This tends to occur more for something temporary than fixed ones; much like ser/estar, but it's a less concrete rule. Generally *ter* is used to indicate possession; as a general rule, where an English "I have..." couldn't be logically substituted for "I possess...", it's more likely that you'd use "Estou com..." than "Tenho...".

In many cases "estar com" will be much more common, but *ter* isn't *wrong* per se, just a little stilted and old-fashioned sounding.

Examples:

For things on your person:

> "Você está com a chave?"
>   
>
>   "Do you have the key?"

For things you "have" that aren't yours.

> "Ainda estou com o livro dele"
>   
>
>   "I still have his book"

Many adjectives in English only have a noun in Portuguese, for example, in Portuguese you cannot "be thirsty", only "have thirst".

For feelings or emotions expressed with a noun

> "estou com medo."
>   
>
>   "I'm afraid." ("I am with fear" > "I have fear")
>
> "Estou com esperança que vai dar certo"
>   
>
>   "I'm hopeful that everything will work out"

For descriptions of temporary characteristics which use nouns (usually these are achieved with adjectives in English).

> "Estou com fome"
>   
>
>   "I'm hungry"
>
> "O meu celular está sem bateria"
>   
>
>   "My phone is out of battery"

(This applies to Brazilians; I think *ter* might be more common in Portugal.)

Comment: I have some intuitions about the semantic distinctions between *ter* and *estar com* in some specific situations, but I'm not 100% confident about them.  In any case, that warrants it's own question (which I may well post in the near future).

Comment: Yes, *ter* is more common in Portugal: "tenho o teu livro" ("I've got your book) is perfectly idiomatic in Portugal. Those adjectives do exist in Portuguese, even if we tend to say *estou com/tenho* + noun: *estou sedento/sequioso, receoso, esperançado/esperançoso, faminto/esfaimado*.

Comment: @Jacinto I didn't know most of those words, thanks. I've never heard anyone say "está sonolento?" or "estou invejoso" etc.  Maybe it's one of those things like "I feel a lot of happiness" or "I have a lot of fatigue" which aren't technically wrong, but just aren't idiomatic?

Comment: *Estou invejoso* is not idiomatic (but "ele é um invejoso" is); the others are idiomatic, just not nearly as common as *estou com/tenho* + noun (*estou cansado* is common). Some have their own conotations or are more likely to be used metaphorically, e.g. *sedendo de poder*; I say *estou esfaimado* humorously to mean that I'm very hungry, etc.

Comment: *Estou cansado* was in response to your "I have a lot of fatigue"; not the same as *sonolento* or *ensonado*, no,

Comment: [let us continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54683/discussion-between-some-guy-and-jacinto)

Answer (score 0):

To be with.

I'm with my brother (Eu estou com meu irmão)
I'm with your television (Eu estou com sua televisão)
I'm with your bicycle (Eu estou com sua bicicleta)

Comment: "I'm with your television" não faz muito sentido em Inglês, amigo. Parece que você e o televisão saíram juntos, e tá comendo um sushi no shopping.  "Estou com o seu televisão, chega aí vamo dar um rolê" kkk.